# Dictionary elements to string

Tags: python

I'm looking for an elegant way to encode values of dictionary objects to the string type. Like the following:

```
{"a":"b","c":1,"e":None,"g":True}
```

to

```
{"a":"b","c":"1","e":"None","g":"True"}
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple with another dict comprehension:

```
a = {"a":"b","c":1,"e":None,"g":True}
a = {k:str(v) for k,v in a.items()}
```

or if you don't want to rebuild the dictionary, do it the old way:

```
for k in a.keys():
    a[k] = str(a[k])
```

(BTW no fear of overhead of converting already existing `str` to `str`: [Should I avoid converting to a string if a value is already a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223125/should-i-avoid-converting-to-a-string-if-a-value-is-already-a-string))