# How do I reset the random integer so that I have another number when I guessed right

Tags: python

How do I reset the random integer when I guessed right. I'm a beginner and could you give me some tips, that help me to write an better code.

```
from random import randint
##Guess a number from 1 to 100
##Made by 
##vers. 0.01beta

name = str(input("how ya name bruh:"))

randm = randint(1, 99)

guesstaken = str(int(0))

while True:
    user_guess = int(input(name + " " + "enter a number:"))

    if user_guess == randm:
       print("you guessed" + " " + "right" + ", " + name)
       SystemExit

    elif user_guess >= randm:
       print("guess lower")
       guesstaken = guesstaken + str(int(1))

    elif user_guess <= randm:
       print("guess higher")
    guesstaken = guesstaken + str(int(1))
```

Comment: Do `randm = randint(1, 99)` again

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing `name = str(input("how ya name bruh:"))` instead of just `name = input("how ya name bruh:")`? I've been seeing this style a lot among question-askers lately and I want to know where the trend's coming from.

Comment: i had erors and by adding this they dont showed up after

Comment: @Kevin that's a (bad) way to make it portable for python 2 and 3 (instead of raw_input). And that doesn't hurt much: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223125/should-i-avoid-converting-to-a-string-if-a-value-is-already-a-string apart from the security issue of `input` in python 2.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But if I enter "Steve" for that prompt, it's going to crash with a NameError in Python 2 regardless of whether you put a str() around it or not.

Comment: @master_of_not_knowlege, that's interesting... What error in particular did you get?

Comment: @Kevin. not if you put it between quotes; no but I see your point. It's useless, yes.

Comment: @Kevin if i remove str it shows this error TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Interesting. That happens if you remove the `str` from line 6, `name = str(input("how ya name bruh:"))`? Are you sure you aren't removing something from a different `input` call? Because I'd only expect that error to occur if you removed the `int()` from line 13, `user_guess = int(input(name + " " + "enter a number:"))`

Comment: To cut directly to my point: you seem to have adopted a policy of "always explicitly convert the return value of `input` to the type you want the value to be", but in reality this is only necessary if you want the type to be something other than a string. `input` always returns a string, so no conversion is necessary if you want it to be a string. (In Python 3.X)

Comment: @Kevin i removed it from line 6 and an error appeared. Now i wrote it back in and deleted it from line 13 and the same error appears again

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the code you posted. As mentioned in the comments, the `str()` call in `name = str(input("how ya name bruh:"))` is pointless because the Python 3 `input()` function *always* returns a string; calling `str()` on an object that's already a string just returns that object. So it doesn't hurt anything, but it adds unnecessary clutter to the code.

Similarly, the expression `int(1)` is redundant because 1 is already an integer. And calling `int()` on an integer object just returns the original integer object.

However, `guesstaken = guesstaken + str(int(1))` is strange. It *doesn't* perform arithmetic it does string concatenation because both `guesstaken` and `str(int(1))` are strings. Here's a short demo of what it does.

```
s = '0'
for i in range(5):
    s = s + '1'
    print(s)
```

**output**

```
01
011
0111
01111
011111
```

With that stuff out of the way we can get onto your question. :) You want to know how to get a new random integer once the player has guessed the correct number. That's simple: we just put the code inside another `while` loop. We also need to ask the player if they want to play again so that we have some way of breaking out of that loop and exiting the program.

Here is a repaired version of your code, with that extra `while` loop. I've used the string `.format()` method to make the printing code cleaner.

```
''' Guess a number from 1 to 100 '''

from random import randint

name = input("What's your name? ")
prompt = name + " enter a number: "

while True:
    randm = randint(1, 99)
    guesstaken = 0
    while True:
        user_guess = int(input(prompt))
        guesstaken += 1

        if user_guess == randm:
            print("You guessed {} {}, in {} guesses".format(randm, name, guesstaken))
            # break out of inner loop
            break
        elif user_guess >= randm:
            print("Guess lower")
        elif user_guess <= randm:
            print("Guess higher")

    # Play again if user inputs "y" or "Y"
    if input("Play again? [y/N] ").lower() != "y":
        # break out of outer loop
        break

print("Thanks for playing, {}.".format(name))
```

**demo**

```
What's your name? PM 2Ring
PM 2Ring enter a number: 50
Guess lower
PM 2Ring enter a number: 25
Guess higher
PM 2Ring enter a number: 37
Guess lower
PM 2Ring enter a number: 31
Guess higher
PM 2Ring enter a number: 34
Guess lower
PM 2Ring enter a number: 33
Guess lower
PM 2Ring enter a number: 32
You guessed 32 PM 2Ring, in 7 guesses
Play again? [y/N] y
PM 2Ring enter a number: 64
Guess lower
PM 2Ring enter a number: 32
Guess lower
PM 2Ring enter a number: 16
Guess higher
PM 2Ring enter a number: 24
Guess higher
PM 2Ring enter a number: 28
Guess lower
PM 2Ring enter a number: 26
You guessed 26 PM 2Ring, in 6 guesses
Play again? [y/N] n
Thanks for playing, PM 2Ring.
```

Answer (score -1):

Just assign `randm` to `randint(1, 99)` (do `randm = randint(1,99)` again).

Also, if what you want is Python to forget the variable use `del`, but it's completely unnecessary.