# How does this string add to this int

Tags: python, string, int

I was under the impression that in Python it was necessary to write (str) when converting an int to a str, but in this case, if the user inputs a number, it still executes fine

```
print('Enter a name.')
name = input()
if name:
    print('Thank you for entering a name, ' + name)
else:
    print('You did not enter a name.')
```

I didn't need to write + str(name) on line 4 when the input entered was 1, for example (or any number).

Comment: Because you are using Python 3 in which `input()` always returns the string type object (unlike Python 2.x)

Comment: So if this were python2, which we still use at work, what would I have to do differently?

Comment: In Python 2, pretty much forget about `input()`. Use `raw_input()`, which is basically the same as `input()` in Python 3.

Comment: And if you are interested in writing your code independent of the Python version,you may simply do `str(name)` with `input()`. There is no harm in type-casting it again

Comment: @MatthewH yes, the Python 2 input works differently, it is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())` which is just... dangerous. Use `raw_input` always, pretty much.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri no harm at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223125/should-i-avoid-converting-to-a-string-if-a-value-is-already-a-string (or use `format` instead)

Comment: ok guys, I appreciate all the answers. I'll post more questions as they come, this was sufficient. Have a great one

Comment: Be careful to check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)  before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs on `input` then you will see this line that refers to your scenario:

> The function reads a line from input, converts it to a **`string`** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

We can also see this in the interpreter:

```
>>> type(input())

<class 'str'>
```

---

And, to clarify, Python will *never* return an `int` from `input()`, you always need to convert if you want to do arithmetic operations or otherwise.

---

Note that the behaviour is different in Python **2** which offers `input()` and `raw_input()`. The first of which will convert the input to the appropriate data type (such as `int`) whereas the latter will function the same as `input()` in Python **3**.

This can again be tested in the interpreter:

```
>>> type(input())
5
<type 'int'>
>>> type(raw_input())
5
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Python does some stuff in the background to figure out what the variable  types are. Plus, the input from `input` is always a string. You just concatenated two strings.

Comment: Oh, I see. input is always a string.

Comment: Because when the user enters `5`, Python gets `'5'`. This is just how `input` works. Whatever you type will be a string to python until you convert it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The function `input` always returns a string.  What you just witnessed is a [string concatenation](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python).

If you wanted to convert the results of `input` into a different type, say integers, then you can do:

`x = int(input("Enter a number"))`

This will raise an error if the input cannot be expressed as an `int` type though.  You can do additional parsing or type testing (e.g. `isinstance()` or `type() is...`) depending on the complexity of the input you're expecting.