# float() object id creation order

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

```
float(1.0) is float(1.0) #True
float(1) is float(1) #False
```

I've isolated the float() oddity here to the object creation order, because

```
x1 = float(1)
x2 = float(1)
x1 is x2 #False
id(x1) == id(x2) #False
y1 = float(1.0)
y2 = float(1.0)
y1 is y2 #True
id(y1) == id(y2) #True
```

Note: I've done checks on the precision of the floats and it is not the reason why this is happening.

I wish to understand why and how is Python deciding to create float objects.
Why is float(1.0) pointing to the same object while float(1) points to 2 different objects when either are created twice?

Also, for further reference:

```
float(1) is float(1) #False
id(float(1)) == id(float(1)) #True
float(1.0) is float(1.0) #True
id(float(1.0)) == id(float(1.0)) #True
```

Comment: `is` is not same as `==`.

Comment: IornPython ... all 4 statements are false

Comment: @Austin I am well aware that `is` is not the same as `==`. Please read the question. I am clearly asking about the object creation order.

Comment: @ycx, I was not answering your question, that's why it's a comment.

Comment: @wim Me. Curosity. Yes.

Comment: @Austin Duly noted. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> float(1.0) is float(1.0)
True
```

That's because `float` returns the object itself because it's already a `float` (same for strings BTW [Should I avoid converting to a string if a value is already a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223125/should-i-avoid-converting-to-a-string-if-a-value-is-already-a-string)).

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c) to confirm (with added comments):

```
static PyObject *
float_float(PyObject *v)
{
    if (PyFloat_CheckExact(v))   // if v is already a float, just increase reference and return the same object
        Py_INCREF(v);
    else
        // else create a new float object using the input value
        v = PyFloat_FromDouble(((PyFloatObject *)v)->ob_fval);
    return v;
}
```

And the reference on literal `1.0` is probably shared when compiled (that's implementation defined, and that's the only explanation I can think of, [Dunes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53749720/6451573) explains it much better), so it's the same as `1.0 is 1.0`.

```
>>> float(1) is float(1)
False
```

Python has to create floating point objects for each side, so it's different. There isn't any floating point interning like integers.

And last fun part:

```
>>> id(float(1)) == id(float(2))
True
```

because the `float` object is garbage collected after `id` has been called, so id is *reused*, even if the literal values are *different* as the above example shows (as exposed in [Unnamed Python objects have the same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802740/unnamed-python-objects-have-the-same-id) or [Why is the id of a Python class not unique when called quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753364/why-is-the-id-of-a-python-class-not-unique-when-called-quickly)).

Comment: Can you address the last codeblock in further reference? If what you said is true, why doesn't `id(float(1)) == id(float(1))` behave the same way as `float(1) is float(1)` when called?  
How exactly is it being implemented and do I have to go to the CPython level to see it or which part of `help(float)` can address this?

Comment: @ycx Intuitively float(1.0) will not create a new object but refer to the original object containing the value of 1.0. So every time you call float(with_float_value) it is referring to the previous object rather than creating the new object. But `float(1)` will have to create a new object each time so its id will be different everytime.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre -I saw your edits and they have answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: it was a very interesting question!

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre However, is there anywhere in the documentation of Python or help(float) that addresses the part where it takes the float as it is and does a conversion for int?

Comment: Concerning your last point: to be exact, not the object is reused, but the 2nd object is created at the same address as the 1st object.

Comment: @glglgl not saying otherwise, my answer says the _id_ is reused, not the _object_

Comment: @ycx checked the source code and edited my answer. The last point that I have to guess is the shared references of float literals, I don't have a reference (haha) for that.

Comment: Worth noting that the reuse of the `id` for two consecutive objects is a quirk of CPython. It's practically guaranteed to happen in CPython, but practically guaranteed to *not* happen in every other Python implementation I know of.

Comment: @DanielPryden I'll link to this other SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802740/unnamed-python-objects-have-the-same-id

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I would actually recommend linking to this one instead: [Why is the id of a Python class not unique when called quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753364/why-is-the-id-of-a-python-class-not-unique-when-called-quickly)

Answer (score 3):

`1.0` is literal syntax for a float object, and so the interpreter has to create a float object that it can pass to `float`. Since floats are immutable, the `float` function can just return the object unchanged. On the other hand `1` is literal syntax for an integer. As such, the `float` function must create a new float object. Within the same block of code the interpreter *sometimes* (not always) is able to identify that two literals for immutable objects are identical then it is able to cache that object and reuse for other references. This is an internal memory optimisation and should not be relied upon.

Thus:

```
def f():
    x = 1.0
    y = float(1.0)
    z = float(x)
    assert x is y # x and y are the same object
    assert x is z # z is also the same as both x and y
f()
```

But:

```
def f():
    return 1.0

def g():
    return 1.0

assert f() is not g() # The interpreter was not able to detect it could reuse the same object
```

Long story short, sometimes numbers in python that are equal *might* also be the exact same object, but that this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation about immutability and literals. Would you also mind explaining the bit on `float(1) is float(1) #False; id(float(1)) == id(float(1)) #True`? Is it as what Jean-François Fabre said in his answer about the garbage collection or do you have a better explanation?

Comment: @ycx I have added 2 links about that in my answer. Both answers complete themselves beautifully if you ask me. The part about python reusing the same object only in the same expression was cool.